# Class generation from XSD during runtime

Tags: c#

How do I generate a C# class from XSD at runtime?

Additionally, how do it list the properties that are contained by the type?

Comment: And after having generated them, what would you do? You would have classes and....

Comment: I'd shuffle the data a bit, serialize and throw it as an xml to the DB

Comment: As written, you can't. You can't easily program against "unknown" classes. How would you write the code? You can't write *ClassThatWillBeGeneratedAtRuntime1 foo = something*

Comment: I can use the ExpandoObject from System.Dynamic Namespace

Comment: Aaah... Yes :-) But then you don't need classes, you only need to load your xml in an ExpandoObject (in a group of interlinked ExpandoObject). I think JSon.Net can do it.

Comment: This is sounding more and more like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don;t think it's an xy problem. I still don;t know how to go from xsd to xml (or a class) in runtime. And this is the requirement of the app.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know how this works. Nobody can answer my question and all that I'm getting is a -1. And all the comments that are of no value get +1s. That should be the question of itself...no comment

Comment: Dave, (in my opinion) you haven't clearly described the problem, which is why it at least appears to be an xy problem. What is it that you are trying to do? do something with a loaded xml? XML serialization? If you plan on using dynamic then it sounds as though you already know some things about the objects you are expecting to receive.

Comment: To be more clear, I'm not asking about the architecture of the system but just the technical bits. I have a xsd and I need to generate a dynamic clas out of it in order to let the user fill the properties. Then it should be serialized and stored in the db.

Comment: But then why is a class needed? you can just [read in the schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04x694fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and treat it as an xml for its entire lifetime in your program (dynamic textboxes et al)

Comment: Yeah that's surely a right direction to go  (+1) but wouldn;t be it just simpler to have the class out of this. This way it's more convenient to work with and I'd assure type safety?

Comment: Yes it would be but you have no real way of doing that, and definitely no way of assuring type safety, Now if the xsd is something that you hold onto then you can just create the solid class in code and create a test that validates an xml document created from that class meets the schema (see serialization)

Answer (score 3):

It definitely is possible.. and not too complicated. You just have to add some differen techniques.
You can use the "Description Importer" to import Service descriptions in runtime. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedescription(v=vs.110).aspx)

What I did was basically creating following steps:

1) Get the WSDL file with a reader (locally or remote, different approaches)

```
XmlTextReader myXmlReader;
myWebService = new WebServiceImporterCompiler(WSDLPath, soapVersion);

if (useLocalWSDL)
{
     FileWebRequest wr = (FileWebRequest)FileWebRequest.Create(WSDLPath);
     FileWebResponse wres = (FileWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
     myXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(wres.GetResponseStream());
}
else
{
     Uri uri = new Uri(WSDLPath); //WEBSERVICE URI
     HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri.OriginalString + "?wsdl");
     wr.Credentials = wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password ?? "");
     HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
     myXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(wres.GetResponseStream());
}
```

2) Build an assembly from the definition / myXmlReader

Check if the xml is readable

```
if (!System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.CanRead(myXmlReader)) 
{
           throw new IOException("WSDL not readable");
}
```

Load importer with some basic options (you might add / change something here)
I create an assembly (dll) but with the switch **parameters.GenerateInMemory** you will be able to generate an in memory class.

```
ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
ServiceDescription serviceDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(myXmlReader);
descriptionImporter.ProtocolName = soapVersion.ToString(); // EITHER SOAP OR SOAP12
descriptionImporter.AddServiceDescription(serviceDescription, null, null);
descriptionImporter.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
descriptionImporter.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
```

Compile assembly with CodeDomProvider

```
CodeCompileUnit codeUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace();
codeUnit.Namespaces.Add(codeNamespace); // Add additional Namespaces
ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings importWarnings = descriptionImporter.Import(codeNamespace, codeUnit);
if (importWarnings == 0)
{
      using (CodeDomProvider compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
      {
           string[] references = { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Xml.dll" };
           CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(references); 
           parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
           parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
           parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
           parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";
           parameters.TempFiles = new TempFileCollection(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "xxx", false);
           parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

           results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, CSharpCode);
           foreach (CompilerError cError in results.Errors)
           {
               // log errors
           }
           if (results.Errors.Count > 0 || results.CompiledAssembly == null) throw new Exception("Kompilierfehler bei Assemblyerstellung");
       }
 }
```

3) Use the generated asssembly object to invoke methods for example for calling the service

```
public T InvokeMethod <T>(Assembly assembly, string serviceNameToCall, MethodInfo methodToCall)
{
        SoapHttpClientProtocol mySoapProtocoll;
    try
    {
         object serviceInstance = myAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceNameToCall);
         mySoapProtocoll = (SoapHttpClientProtocol)serviceInstance;
         mySoapProtocoll.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; // or use your own
         object myObject = (T)ServiceType.InvokeMember(methodToCall, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, mySoapProtocoll, args);
    }
}
```

To get the methodInfo object / available methods use reflections to iterate over the assembly / classes.

A complete guide on reflections can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial)